# How can I Loop Through 3D NIFTI Image in Python

Tags: python, nifti

For a project I am doing, I want to write a script that can calculate the total brain volume of an MRI image in the nifti format (.nii extension). What I don't know how to do is loop through all the individual voxels and extract the integer data inside. Does someone know how to do this?

This is the code I used to load a particular nifti image in Python:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import os

path = '/Users/arnavlohe/Desktop/ADNI_002_S_0782_MR_MP-RAGE_REPEAT_br_raw_20060814234209235_1_S17836_I20520_be_be_mixeltype.nii'
img = nib.load(path)
print(img)
```

And this is the resulting output/image data:

```
<class 'nibabel.nifti1.Nifti1Image'>
data shape (166, 256, 256)
affine: 
[[  1.20000184   0.           0.         113.7559967 ]
 [  0.           0.9375       0.         158.26870728]
 [  0.           0.           0.9375     418.0289917 ]
 [  0.           0.           0.           1.        ]]
metadata:
<class 'nibabel.nifti1.Nifti1Header'> object, endian='<'
sizeof_hdr      : 348
data_type       : 
db_name         : 
extents         : 0
session_error   : 0
regular         : r
dim_info        : 0
dim             : [  3 166 256 256   1   1   1   1]
intent_p1       : 0.0
intent_p2       : 0.0
intent_p3       : 0.0
intent_code     : none
datatype        : int32
bitpix          : 32
slice_start     : 0
pixdim          : [1.        1.2000018 0.9375    0.9375    1.        0.        
0.
 0.       ]
...
```

This is all the information I can provide, and I apologize that my question is not any more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You may combine [`get_fdata()`](http://nipy.org/nibabel/nibabel_images.html#getting-the-image-data-the-easy-way) to retrieve the image data as a NumPy array:

```
img = nib.load(path)
data = img.get_fdata()
```

and [NumPy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing) to access voxels, for example:

```
data[1,1,1]
```

Finally note that you may ask such questions on [Neurostars](https://neurostars.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Do not loop over every voxel, that will be extremely slow (will take minutes to run). Instead, use numpy operations that work with the entire array. I suggest using a threshold:

```
img = nib.load(path)
voxel_volume = np.prod(img.header['pixdim'][1:4])
data = img.get_fdata()
threshold = 0
mask = np.where(data > threshold, 1, 0)
volume = voxel_volume*np.sum(mask)
print(volume/1000, "cm³")
```

Answer (score 0):

Very approximate calculation:

```
img = nib.load(path)
voxel_volume = np.prod(img.header['pixdim'][1:4])
voxel_count = np.count_nonzero(img.get_fdata())
print(voxel_volume*voxel_count/1000, "cm³")
```